# Ignore events from children of a ScrollViewer while scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-7

Alright here is my issue.  I have a Pivot view.  Inside that pivot view a scroll viewer containing many stack panels and grids.  On some of the grids I have MouseButton Up Events.  What is happening is if I flick the scroll it scrolls as expected but when I release my finger most of the time it fires off the event from mousebutton up.  Because technically I let up.  The problem is these grids completely fill the screen so finding an area without a mousebutton up to scroll is near impossible.  What I want to happen is if the user flicked to scroll I would ideally like it to ignore the mousebutton up event.  It does this successfully sometimes but pretty rarely and I have noticed I have to flick pretty fast for it to work as expected.

Any ideas on how to prevent this activity.  I assume there is as Listboxes work perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting a bool for when the scrollviewer was scrolling and based on that allowing the mouseup action to run my code.  Here is the the site I used to implement the bool based on scrolling status.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/07/23/how-to-detect-when-a-list-is-scrolling-or-not.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i think u should use `windows phone toolkit` `GestureListener` to recognize `flick event`